# Can I refinance an car registered in Texas which is under my grandparents name with a loan in California state where I live

Tags: united-states, car, refinance, auto-loan

Need to know if its even possible to refinance my grandparents car from Texas  to California where I live?

I was looking to apply for a car loan through a credit union bank. I asked EECU but they said I couldn't get the car loan through them because the car is not registered in California.

They suggested I get a Personal Loan. I am not keen as the interest rate on personal loan is high and my credit score is quite good.

The reason for wanting to get my own loan is to pay off the remaining balance of 15,000 on the car so I can establish some more credit score for the pay off of the car.

The bank which lent my grandparents the loan gave them a 7 point something rate which is high even though they have great credit score.

The car dealer was to originally put my name first and them as co signers but he has not done it.

I am tired of having to travel once a year to Texas for the renewal of tags.

Should I try to get a Car Loan in Texas under my name? Will it be more likely to be approved?

Comment: where is the car? Texas? California?

Comment: It seems like a bank might be a good place to start.

Comment: Why have you not registered the car in California?

Comment: It does seem very unlikely you could pull this off.

Comment: Car is used in ca and insiranced there. since they are letting me drive it.car is registered under grandparents name therefore cant register in ca because the live in tx